# Sending image file from spring boot java to python through flask

Tags: java, python, image, spring-boot, flask

So i saw this code from this forum: [Connect Java with Python Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994238/connect-java-with-python-flask)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/add/', methods = ['POST'])
def add_numbers():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        decoded_data = request.data.decode('utf-8')
        params = json.loads(decoded_data)
        return jsonify({'sum': params['x'] + params['y']})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class PostClass {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5000/add/"); //important to add the trailing slash after add
            String[] inputData = {"{\"x\": 5, \"y\": 8, \"text\":\"random text\"}",
                    "{\"x\":5, \"y\":14, \"text\":\"testing\"}"};
            for(String input: inputData){
                byte[] postData = input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(input.length()));
                os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                os.write(postData);
                os.flush();

                if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                            + conn.getResponseCode());
                }

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        (conn.getInputStream())));

                String output;
                System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(output);
                }
                conn.disconnect();
            }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally
        {
            if(conn != null)
            {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It shows how to pass variables from java to python and then from python it will response back json result. What i would like to know is how do you do something similar for file image so that python can use flask.request.files['request from java']. I require to send file image to python for python to use machine learning to predict the image. Kindly assist. Sorry if the question sounds lame. I only have 6 months experience. This is the python code receive response from my android studio. I would like to implement the same request from my spring boot so that i will be using the same python that can receive request from both android and java.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_request():
    imagefile = flask.request.files['image']
    # to extract file name
    filename = werkzeug.utils.secure_filename(imagefile.filename)
    print("\nReceived image File name: " + imagefile.filename)
    imagefile.save(filename)
        

    imageML = load_img('androidFlask.jpg', color_mode='rgb', target_size= (224,224))
    
    imageArray = img_to_array(imageML)
    imageArray = np.expand_dims(imageArray, axis = 0)
    imageArray = imageArray/255.0
    
    
    prediction = breedModel.predict(imageArray)
    predicted_class = np.argmax(np.round(prediction), axis = 1)
    

    result = str(label_mapping[predicted_class[0]])    
    result = result.replace("_", " ")

    return result


app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have similar problems as me, you can take a look into this post. [Sending files using POST with HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection)
It seems like a solution to my problem.